# process of running linux executable

Tags: c, linux, bootloader

Is there good documentation of what happen when I run some executable in Linux. For example: I start `./a.out`, so probably some bootloader assembly is run (come with c runtime?), and it finds start symbol in program, doing dynamic relocation, finally call `main`.

I know the above is not correct, but looking for detailed documentation of how this process happen. Can you please explain, or point to links or books that do?

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/8/ld-linux and other info pages related to it may also help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For dynamic linked programs, the kernel detects the `PT_INTERP` header in the ELF file and first mmaps the dynamic linker (`/lib/ld-linux.so.2` or similar), and starts execution at the `e_entry` address from the main ELF header of the dynamic linker. The initial state of the stack contains the information the dynamic linker needs to find the main program binary (already in memory). It's responsible for reading this and finding all the additional libraries that must be loaded, loading them, performing relocations, and jumping to the `e_entry` address of the main program.

For static linked programs, the kernel uses the `e_entry` address from the main program's ELF header directly.

In either case, the main program begins with a routine written in assembly traditionally called `_start` (but the name is not important as long as its address is in the `e_entry` field of the ELF header). It uses the initial stack contents to determine `argc`, `argv`, `environ`, etc. and calls the right implementation-internal functions (usually written in C) to run global constructors (if any) and perform any libc initialization needed prior to the entry to `main`. This usually ends with a call to `exit(main(argc, argv));` or equivalent.

Comment: Thanks, R, but how does kernel know that program is dynamically linked or statically linked? And are not all Linux programs dynamic linked (At least with libc?)

Comment: As much as Drepper wishes you had to dynamic link everything, no, there is no requirement to use dynamic linking. `gcc -static` will generate a static-linked binary. The kernel knows the difference by the presence or absence of a `PT_INTERP` program header in the ELF.

Comment: R.. - where can I found the source code of dynamic linker to learn? I mean of ld-linux?

Comment: It's part of glibc, and it's rather unwieldy reading... There's a simpler version that comes with uClibc which might be more educational to read.

Answer (score 1):

A book "[Linker and Loader](http://books.google.com/books/about/Linkers_and_loaders.html?id=Id9cYsIdjIwC)" gives a detail description about the loading process. Maybe it can give you some help on the problem.

Comment: but does it talk about modern linux?

Comment: It talks more about the general principles. You can find linux-related documents follow @Torp 's advice.